How to use a vue 3 variable in scss
I'm currently using vue 3. In my package.json I have:
"dependencies": {
        "@vue/compat": "^3.4.34",
        "@vue/runtime-dom": "^3.4.34",
        "@vue/typescript": "^1.8.20",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
        "core-js": "^3.37.1",
        "detect-browser": "^4.8.0",
        "intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "vue": "^3.4.34",
        "vue-router": "^4.4.0",
        "vue-virtual-scroller": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^3.10.2"
    },

I created a reactive variable in my vue component:
const testCol = ref(3) that I am hoping to use in scss. I am aware in vue 2 this is difficult but since I am using vue 3 I believe it is feasible as indicated here: VueJS & Vuetify - How to use JS variables in Sass and https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html
In the same component I have the following scss:
[data-index="2"]> .rcwc-datatable-row {
        min-height: 2em;
        // :nth-child(0) {
        //     border: 1px solid purple;
        // }
;
        .rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(3){
            border:2px solid purple;
            // color: v-bind("testColour");
        }
    }

I am trying to replace the 3 in nth-child with a variable. My initial thought is to:
.rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(v-bind("testCol"){
    border:2px solid purple;
}

but I get the error:
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Expected "n".
   ╷
18 │         .rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(v-bind("testCol")){
   │                                        ^
   ╵
  src\components\RcWorksheet\RcWorksheetBase.vue 18:40  root stylesheet

I also tried:
$test: v-bind("testCol");
.rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(#{$test}){
    border:2px solid purple;
}

but I get the error:
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Expected "n".
  ┌──> src\components\RcWorksheet\RcWorksheetBase.vue
18│         .rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(#{$test}){
  │                                          ^^^^^ 
  ╵
  ╷
1 │ .rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(v-bind(testCol))
  │                                ━ error in interpolated output
  ╵
  src\components\RcWorksheet\RcWorksheetBase.vue 18:42  root stylesheet

I decided to see if it's because it doesn't like v-bind in scss or simply because of the nth-child.
If I am to add:
const testColour = ref("red");


.rcwc-datatable-cell:nth-child(3){
    border:2px solid purple;
    color: v-bind("testColour");
}

The there are no complaints. So what am I doing wrong? Is there something special with nth-child such that I cannot use v-bind with it?

:nth-child(v-bind("testCol") doesn't make sense. If you can't express a class with CSS vars like :nth-child(var(--testCol)), you can't do this with v-bind, there's no magic behind it. As long as you modify the style with a script, you can add a style or class programmatically depending on "testCol" value, there's no need for nth pseudoclass

Can you explain what you mean? From the vue docs: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html, v-bind seems to be viable. Do you know what I can do to make the argument in the nth-child a variable from vue?

See the explanation, "The actual value will be compiled into a hashed CSS custom property, so the CSS is still static. The custom property will be applied to the component's root element via inline styles and reactively updated if the source value changes." As I said, if you can't do :nth-child(var(--testCol)) in pure css (you can't), you can't do this with vue-specific things like v-bind
